# developing mobile application with visual studio and Apache Cordova

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-cordova

I just found that VS 2013 community edition is free for personal use and I noted on MSVC site that I can use Visual Studio 2013 with Apache Cordova to build multi platform mobile applications.

How can I do this? Is there any tutorial on this?

Can I develop multi platform mobile application with VS community edition?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the plugin newly updated [Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova CTP3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=42675).

You can find multiple tutorial explaining the path to create a first application easily on a search engine.